# My navigation bar is showing issues never seen before by me

Tags: html, css

As you read on the title, I've been trying to make a navigation bar but I'm having several issues I haven't experienced before. I even made a list:

1. Buttons sticking into the navigation bar even though they don't belong in the `div` class.

Navigation Bar

[image]

2. Well now, I've seen this before, but I've gotten a bit rusty on `HTML` and don't quite remember how to fix it. If you can't tell, the links are not lined up with the text/logo. How can I fix this? I'm trying to make it slim.

```css
background-color: #252036;

}
#navigation-container {
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 70%;
}
.navigation-bar {
  background-color: #1c172c;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: right;
}
.navigation-bar ul {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: right;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.navigation-bar li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  display: inline;
  text-align: right;
}
.navigation-bar li a {
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: basic;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 70px;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
#menu {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation-bar">
  <div id="navigation-container">
    <h1>SINUS</h1>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<button>Download</button>
```

Comment: `<link><a href="#">Home</a></link>` should be `<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>` at least.

Comment: I know but it's pretty much the same thing. I was testing something, which resulted in me changing it from <li> to <link> and i forgot to undo my change. EDIT: Realised my mistake haha, thanks!

Comment: Your code seems to be missing something. what do you exactly want to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to make a navigation bar with the text on the left side and with the links on the right side.

Answer (score 0):

1. It is sticking because of `position: fixed;`. The button doesn't see the `.navigation-bar`. Add padding to a parent that contains these elements.
2. `h1` needs to have `display:inline-block;`. `ul` is just below `h1` now.

Comment: I dont quite understand your instructions. What do you mean by "add padding to a parent that contains these elements"?